# How to show all names for identical contract in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have query like this, and i shows me sort of good results

```
select 
    vup.UgovorId, 
    count(P.Naziv) as BROJNAZIVA 
from 
    [TEST_Ugovori_Prod].dbo.VezaUgovorPartner as vup 
inner join 
    [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].[dbo].[Partner] as p on vup.PartnerId = p.PartnerID 
group by 
    vup.UgovorId
```

Results are like this (first row is vup.UgovorId, second is p.Naziv):

```
1264 1
1265 3
```

But I want to show all p.Naziv when that row has more then one for that vup.UgovorId like string so I would be like this:

```
1264 "Mark"
1265 "Jerry, Philip, Tom"
```

Comment: You need a pivot query for this. Also some sample data and the table structures would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) is the issue you are trying to solve?

I am not sure what technology you are using, but this may at least provide you some guidance.

So your code would look something like this:

```
select 
    vup.UgovorId, 
    substring(
    (
        Select ','+ P.Naziv AS [text()]
        From [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].[dbo].[Partner] as p
        Where vup.PartnerId = p.PartnerID
        ORDER BY P.Naziv
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Names]
from 
    [TEST_Ugovori_Prod].dbo.VezaUgovorPartner as vup
group by vup.UgovorId
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to show all record about same vup.UgovorId, because with this I got p.Naziv but I want all p.Naziv for one vup.UgovorId