# I want to display records for one ID if there is more NUMBER for the same ID

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

For the first ID which is 1265 I want only one record like this(look below), and for now I have three different records for the same ID and that isn't good. You can see that in the first record with ID = 1265 I would like to have concated strings into one separated with ',':

```
1265 MARK, LISA, MAY
```

Here is my code sample:

```
select 
    vup.UgovorId as ID, 
    concat(p.Naziv, p.Naziv) as NUMBER 
from 
    [TEST_Ugovori_Prod].dbo.VezaUgovorPartner as vup 
inner join 
    [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].[dbo].[Partner] as p on vup.PartnerId = p.PartnerID 
group by 
    vup.UgovorId, p.Naziv
order by 
    vup.UgovorId desc
```

Here are my results:

```
1265    MARK  
1265    LISA
1265    MAY
1264    LINDA  
1263    MARTINA
1262    MARKO                                                                                                                                                                                
1261    VIDAKS
1260    PEEKS 
1259    MARCUS
1258    MARKO                                                                                                                                                                                
1257    MATIA                                                                                                                                                                                 
1256    POPOVIC
```

Comment: The `concat(p.Naziv, p.Naziv)` seems like a mistake in your example. The results you've provided would have been `MARKMARK`, `LISALISA`, etc.. if that was what you actually used. Seems you could take that out of your example query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show all names for identical contract in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965582/how-to-show-all-names-for-identical-contract-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, NUMBER = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + NUMBER
           FROM example t2 
           WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM example t1
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

[image]

[[DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/GHRIR53090)

---

If you are having trouble blending with your query above, this should help:

```
SELECT vup.UgovorId as ID, 
     STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + p2.Naziv  
           FROM [TEST_Ugovori_Prod].dbo.VezaUgovorPartner vup2 
           INNER JOIN [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].[dbo].[Partner] p2 ON vup2.PartnerId = p2.PartnerID 
           WHERE vup2.UgovorId = vup.UgovorId   
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') NUMBER
FROM [TEST_Ugovori_Prod].dbo.VezaUgovorPartner vup 
INNER JOIN [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].[dbo].[Partner] p on vup.PartnerId = p.PartnerID 
GROUP BY vup.UgovorId
ORDER BY vup.UgovorId DESC
```

[[Test blend]](http://rextester.com/WWFZI13927)